# Sending email through http with LinkedResource property

Tags: c#

I am trying to compose a email that has a body with a embedded image using LinkedResource. When I try to Post it to our api that connects to the smtp I get this exception:

*System.AggregateException: InvalidOperationException: Timeouts are not supported on this stream.
JsonSerializationException: Error getting value 'ReadTimeout' on 'System.IO.FileStream'.*

This is my code what do I need to change to make this work.

```
class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Mailer();            
    }

    public static void Mailer()
    {
        var imageOne = new LinkedResource("PumpkinSpice.jpg", "image/jpeg");
        imageOne.ContentId = "psl";
        var imageLink = $"<img src=\"cid:{imageOne.ContentId}\"/>"; 
        var listOfResources = new List<LinkedResource> {imageOne};

        var email = new MailInfo()
        {
            ToAddresses = "mcjibbles@foo.com",
            CcAddresses = "jibbles@bar.com",
            BccAddresses = null,
            Subject = "test email",
            Body = "Email body" + imageLink,
            Resources = listOfResources,
            IsHtml = true

        };

        using (var client = CreateClient())
        {
            client.PostAsJsonAsync($"api/email", email).Wait();
        }       
    }

    private static HttpClient CreateClient()
    {
        return new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler { UseDefaultCredentials = true })
        {
            BaseAddress = new Uri("http://fakesite.com/")
        };
    }
}
class MailInfo
{

    public string ToAddresses { get; set; }
    public string CcAddresses { get; set; }
    public string BccAddresses { get; set; }
    public string Subject { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }
    public bool IsHtml { get; set; }
    public List<LinkedResource> Resources { get; set; }

}
```

Api Code

```
public class EmailController : ApiController
{

 [HttpPost]
 public void SendEmail(EmailInformation information)
    {

        using (var message = new MailMessage())
        {
            message.Subject = information.Subject;

            var toAddresses = SplitAddresses(information.ToAddresses);
            foreach (var address in toAddresses)
            {
                message.To.Add(new MailAddress(address));
            }

            message.IsBodyHtml = information.IsHtml;
            message.Body = information.Body;    


            using (var htmlView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(message.Body, null, "text/html"))
            {
                foreach (var resource in information.Resources)
                {
                    htmlView.LinkedResources.Add(resource);
                }
                using (var client = new SmtpClient(WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Smtp"]))
                {
                    message.From = information.FromAddress;

                    client.Send(message);
                }
            }              
        }
    }

    public class EmailInformation
    {       
        public string ToAddresses { get; set; }
        public string FromAddress { get; set; }
        public string CcAddresses { get; set; }
        public string BccAddresses { get; set; }
        public string Subject { get; set; }
        public string Body { get; set; }
        public bool IsHtml { get; set; }
        public List<LinkedResource> Resources { get; set; }
    }
```

}

Comment: What is a `LinkedResource`? Is that your code? Or does it come from a library?

Comment: `LinkedResource` is from the System.Net.Mail namespace

Comment: I never actually see you assign the `LinkedResource` to the `MailInfo`. Anyways, I don't know that `LinkedResource` is going to serialize into useful JSON. What mail API are you trying to use? They likely specify how attachments should be passed.

Comment: I updated it to assign the value. I can add attachments no problem however I am trying to figure out how to embed images into the email body. We are using the 'SmtpClient' class from the System.Net.Mail namespace on our api to send the emails.

Comment: Okay, so this is a custom Web API that your company created. You would need to show that side of it too in order to have an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Using SmtpClient is irrelevant if you can't serialize the data in your client and then deserialize it in your Web API.